# Show that $x^3 - 6x^2 + 11x - 6$ is divisible by $3, \forall x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

Update: I feel as though I'm doing something very wrong here.

[image: It's too easy...must be wrong.]

Thank you all for the great suggestions! I am going to take the suggestions and try to shorten my proof. Again, I appreciate you all!

Show that $x^3 - 6x^2 + 11x - 6$ is divisible by $3, \forall x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Hello, again. I hope that uploading an image of my proof is acceptable. Typing the proof out would be painful, but if typing the proof out is necessary to receive help, then I will do so.

I have tried this proof using several methods: direct, contradiction and induction. Direct proof by using the additive group of $\mathbb{Z_3}$ was the only thing that seemed to work. However, when I choose an integer outside of the group, I still find that I have the same result. I do not know if that is ok. I do not know if this proof is wholly flawed or not. Thank you all for your help and patience.[image: myProof]

Comment: What is the integer *outside the group*?

Comment: @Nightflight I mean that I chose the numbers 3, 4, and 5 and I got the same result.

Comment: can you factorise the cubic - what are its roots?

Comment: The group $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$; it is a set of equivalent classes. It is not quite right to say "integer outside the group $\mathbb{Z}_3$".

Comment: Alt. hint: $\,x^3 \color{red}{-x+x} - 6x^2 + 11x - 6=x^3-x - 6(x^2-2x+1)=x(x-1)(x+1)+3n\,$.

Comment: Thank you @LouisPan. What is the correct way to say what I was intending?

Comment: Note that $x^3-6x^2+11x+6\equiv x(x^2+11)\equiv x(x^2+2)\,(mod\,3)$. Then, take $x=3n, 3n+1$ or $3n+2$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using induction prove $n^3-n$ is divisible by 3 whenever n is a positive number.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276003/using-induction-prove-n3-n-is-divisible-by-3-whenever-n-is-a-positive-number)

Comment: Your $\,f(x) = x^3-x + 3(-2x^2+4x-2)\,$ so it suffices to show $\,3\mid x^3-x\,$ which has been done here hundreds of times, e.g. see the linked dupe and its links.

Answer (score 5):

Your proof is long, but correct. If you know about [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), you can write your polynomial as
$$
x^3-6x^2+11x-6=6\binom{x-1}{3}
$$
which shows that your polynomial is always divisible by $6$ for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, and therefore, by $3$.

Answer (score 3):

I think your proof is much too long.  You have to show this expression is congruent to $0\bmod 3$, so use congruences, and remember that *lil' Fermat* asserts that $x^3\equiv x\mod 3$ for any $x$.

Comment: I have updated my post with a new proof. But, I am not very confident in it.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct but you are going the long way to solve the problem.

Not that for an integer $x$ we have  $$x^3 - 6x^2 + 11x - 6\equiv x^3-x  \equiv x(x-1)(x+1) \pmod 3 $$

Thus you have three consecutive integers and one of them is a multiple of 3

Comment: I suppose that I shouldn't take $x = -1, 0, 1$ to be cases...?

Answer (score 2):

I think your proof is too long, but **flawless**.

Because all integer is one of the $3n, 3n+1, 3n+2$ form, and you prooved at every form.

But I agree with Bernard, your proof is too long.

Basic way to proof is using $x^3-6x^2+11x-6=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$, and it must be multiple of 3 at $3n, 3n+1, 3n+2$ form each.

Comment: I was so wrapped up in figuring this thing out that I didn't stop to think about the simplest thing - checking the zeros. I can take those to be cases and go from there, correct?

Answer (score 2):

I like your proof here is another alternative.

Since this is a cubic let's try completing the cube

$$x^3-6x^2+11-6 = (x-2)^3-x + 2 = (x-2)((x-2)^2-1)=(x-2)(x^2-4x+3)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3).$$

For any $x\neq1,2,3$ Either $x-1$, $x-2$, or $x-3$ will be divisible by three since they are three consecutive numbers. Note also that at least one of the factors is even so not only is your expression divisible by 3, it's actually divisible by 6!